# Difference between set of true sentences and deductive closure

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm reading a chapter on first order arithmetic, and it lists the set of all true sentences (called complete first-order arithmetic and labelled $\Omega$) and the deductive closure of the empty set $\Lambda =_{df} \mathbf{Dc} \emptyset$ that is called "logic".

Are they different sets? I thought that since first-order logic systems are complete, any true sentence is deducible.

Comment: But this is not the same completeness. The completeness of the theory (in a particular model) is not the same as the completeness of the logic.

Comment: Yes, there are two forms of completeness. I am referring to the semantic completeness of first-order predicate calculus. Is every true sentence deducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what is meant by *the set of all true sentences*. Probably it refers to $Th(\mathcal{N})$, [the set of arithmetic sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_arithmetic) that are true in $\mathcal{N}$ ([the standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_arithmetic)). By [Gödel's first incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%F6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#First_incompleteness_theorem) we cannot construct an  effectively generated consistent theory that would prove all these sentences, so the deductive closure of any consistent arithmetic system will be always a proper subset of $Th(\mathcal{N})$.

See also [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem).

**Update** to clarify: Let $T$ be a consistent, effectively generated arithmetic [theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_%28logic%29). By [Gödel's first incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%F6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#First_incompleteness_theorem) there must be some true arithmetic formula $\phi\in Th(\mathcal{N})$ that is not provable in $T$, so $T\not\vdash\phi$.

However, by [Gödel's completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%F6del_completeness_theorem) we have for any $\psi$ that $T\vdash\psi$ iff $T\models\psi$. And because $T\not\vdash\phi$ we get that $T\not\models\phi$. In other words, there must exists a model $M$ of $T$ such that $M\models T$ and $M\not\models\phi$. Because $\phi$ is a true arithmetic formula ($\mathcal{N}\models\phi$), our model $M$ must be different from $\mathcal{N}$. Such models are called [non-standard models of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic). Formula $\phi$ is a true arithmetic formula, but isn's not true in all models of $T$!

So a corollary of Gödel's incompleteness theorem is that we cannot construct a consistent first-order theory of arithmetic that would have no other models than the standard one $\mathcal{N}$. Every theory must have a non-standard model in which some arithmetic truth is false.

Comment: I am struggling with how this fits in with semantic completeness? I thought that if a sentence is true (satisfied by every valuation), then we write $\models \alpha$, and by the semantic completeness it follows that $\vdash \alpha$, i.e. the sentence is deducible?

Comment: @DarrenNaylor I updated the answer with an explanation how Gödel's completeness and incompleteness theorems go together.